# Count the number of elements in an array fulfilling a simple condition

Tags: arrays, r

I am just jumping back into R after a long time away and I am surprised by how simple some of the things are to do. I have created 3 arrays:

```
Xs = runif(N, min=-1, max=1);
Ys = runif(N, min=-1, max=1);
Rs = sqrt( Xs^2 + Ys^2 );
```

where, obviously, X and Y (together) define N points within the (-1,1) square and R is the vector defining the distances of these points.

If I want to count the number of elements in `Rs` which are less than or equal to 1, is there a simple inl-line command to do this?

Comment: `table(Rs<=1)` or `sum(Rs<=1)`

Comment: Also semicolons don't do anything in R

Comment: Should be close (in the statistical sense) to N*0.7853982 =  N*pi/4.  `pi/4
[1] 0.7853982
> N=1000
> sum(Rs <= 1 )
[1] 786`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sum( Rs <= 1 )
```

`Rs <= 1` yields a logical vector.  `TRUE` equals 1; `FALSE` equals 0.